# bash: write to a unicode file

Tags: bash, unicode

#### Aim

I just need to write text to a unicode file but it doesn't seam to be that easy.

The result should be exactly the same as when I open a notepad, enter the following text and save it with unicode encoding:

> ä
> öü

#### Attempt

My attempt, to write to an already existing file, looks like this:

```
(
echo ä
echo öü
)>text.txt
```

The Result is this:

> ꓃਍뛃볃਍

Comment: No such thing as a Unicode file; files are byte streams, and can be identified as containing text encoded as UTF-8, UTF-16, etc. The important thing is that you decode the file (for viewing) using the same encoding you used when writing to it.

Comment: That *should* work if your locale is set up correctly. What are you using to *view* the file? Notepad in particular is known to guess the encoding, and sometimes guess wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the probably multiple ways you can do this is with `printf` or `echo -e` and using the unicode value of the character. So for example:

```
$ echo -e '\u00E4'
ä
```

So you simply can redirect the output wherever you need it:

```
$ printf  '\u00E4' | tee unicode
ä
```

Comment: You should prefer `printf` over `echo -e`.

Comment: printf is a lot more versatile, but if you only need to print three characters probably it doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: It's much more reliable rather than versatile heh :)

Comment: This depends on which `echo` and which version of Bash you have, in the case of Bash's built-in `echo`.

Comment: I'll concede that one and add it to the answer. Which one to use would be enough for a question itself https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: It also depends on how you have `bash` configured (cf the `xpg_echo` option). Long story short: forget `echo` exists, and use `printf` for everything.